# Trying to add a css background-image property to an element but it keeps adding spaces in my url

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

I'm trying to add a **CSS** background-image property to an element but it keeps adding spaces in my url. I'm building the frontend of an app using a theme, using laravel for the backend.

```
$('.background-image-maker').each(function () {
    var imgURL = $(this).next('.holder-image').find('img').attr('src');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgURL + ')');
});
```

But the it keeps adding a space to my img src. Here is how it looks when I inspect it:

```
<div class="background-image-maker" style="background-image: url("/storage/listings\a ugust2018\b Z3oR5cjVtLXQXSkGinM.jpg");"></div>
```

Any idea on how to fix the problem? Here is the **HTML** section:

```
<div class="background-image-maker" />
<div class="holder-image">
    <img src="/storage/{{ $listing->cover_image }}" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none">
</div>
```

Comment: So the script is out putting `/storage/listings\a ugust2018\b Z3oR5cjVtLXQXSkGinM.jpg` but what is the expected output? Exactly the same but without the space? If so then why not use a simple `replace()` function... I don't use `Laravel` but maybe this example might be of some help? `{!! str_replace(' ', '', $listing->cover_image) !!}` Or in `jQuery` you could use `imgURL.replace(" ", "");`

Answer (score 0):

With the use of `.replace()`

```
 function getBackgroundImageUrl($element) {
    if (!($element instanceof jQuery)) {
      $element = $($element);
    }

    var imageUrl = $element.css('background-image');
    return imageUrl.replace(/(url\(|\)|'|")/gi, ''); // Strip everything but the url itself
  }
```